A question in Natural Deduction for First Order Logic
I have a question on the rules of Natural Deduction for First Order Logic in the Page:
https://leanprover.github.io/logic_and_proof/natural_deduction_for_first_order_logic.html
Is this a proof for $\vdash A(x)\to\forall yA(y)$?
$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{A(x)}1.}{\forall yA(y)}\forall I}
{A(x)\to \forall y A(y)}1.\ \to I$
This seems wrong, but what is the problem? thanks a lot.

The problem is with $(\forall \text I)$: you cannot generalize a variable that is free in an assumption. See the note in your rules-set: "In the introduction rule [for $\forall$], $x$  should not be free in any uncanceled hypothesis. "
